# Trying to convert INR value to equivalent Eth (wei)

Tags: solidity, exchanges

I'm trying to write a smart contract that takes INR as user input and converts it to equivalent eth ( wei ). I looked into chainlink datafeeds, but no luck there. Need advice on how to implement this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly , you need to have a source from which you can get the exchange rates there are 2 ways for it :

1. External API
2. Data Feed services

Next , If  you have the exchange rate, you can write the conversion function in Solidity.

```
solidity code : 
    uint256 convertedEthAmount = inrAmount * exchangeRate / 1e18;
     return convertedEthAmount * 1e18; // convert to wei
```

Lastly , in frontend you have to follow few steps to get these values ,

1. Import the ABI
2. Create web3 instance : `const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(ABI, contractAddress);`
3. Call the solidity function : `contract.methods.convert_Inr_to_Eth(inr_Amount).call()`

Comment: Alright, will try it out. Thanks.